# Magento 2 is not loading the fontawesome cdn library

Tags: magento2, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to load a css library on a magento 2 from cdn:

```
<css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" src_type="url"/>
```

and to do this I insert this link into:

```
/app/design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

and after deployed, cleared the cache and everything, but still not loading it..

Comment: Please share, how you tried to add it in XML.

Comment: basically I have just added that cdn link into the "default_head_blocks.xml" file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then run `php bin/magento cache:flush`.

Comment: great, was everything right, I just had to flush the cache and worked, thank you!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!!!